constrainted optimisation proof using $Ax\leq b$
I am trying to prove the following, let $x^*$ be a local minimum of the constrained optimisation problem- minimise $f(x)$ subject to $Ax\leq b$. I have tried using the KKT 1st order conditions and then tried to get it from that but I'm not sure if I have to try different cases for the active set ie. when $Ax=b$ OR when $Ax<b$ is strict to then get to the final answer, any help would be appreciated.
$$\nabla f(x^*)A^{-1}(Ax^*-b)=0$$

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

is that better?

Yes, it is better.
